# RestAngular Put request in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How can I make a `put` request in `RestAngular`?

This is what I tried.

```
 facUpdatePartner: function (partner)
        {
            var url = "UpdatePartner";
            var result = Restangular.one(url);
            return result.put(partner);
        }
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: i did not saw any error message, from web api side i did not get the values

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you full code but should is something like this:

```
facUpdatePartner: function (partner)
{
    return partner.put();
}
```

the `partner` need to come from a previous getOne or a get with Restangular. For example:

Controller:

```
vm.getCategories = function () {
  Category.get().then(function (categories) {
    vm.categories = categories;
  });
};

vm.getCategories();

vm.update = function(category){
  category.put().then(function(result){
    alert('UPDATED!');
  }).catch(function(err){
    alert('ERROR!');
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
  <td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="category.name">
  </td>    
  <td>
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.update(category)">
  </td>   
</tr>
....
```